# Do I need to manually enable the upnp at the router when running my node?

Tags: go-ethereum

I used the upnp lib for my app. It required manually enable the upnp at the router. My PC is inside the company's network. All connections are controlled by NATs. 
So, I wonder whether GETH's nodes can connect the others by automatically enable the upnp way
Sorry for my bad grammar. Any answers will be appreciated!